# C: Pointer to a function inside structre makes segmentation fault

Tags: c

I have to create linked list. In these lists, I shall define pointer to a function. My Error is whenever I call the function, I got segmentation fault error. Can anyone help in that please, below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct CommandStructure{
    char CommandName[10];
    char ShortKey;
    void (* CommandAction)(void);
} CommandFrame;

typedef struct LinkedCommandsStructure{
    CommandFrame * Entity;
    struct LinkedCommandsStructure * NextCommand;
} Firmware_Command; 


void PrintSEQHelp(){
    printf("HelloPrint \n");
}


CommandFrame * SEQ_Help(){
    CommandFrame * Entity = malloc(sizeof(Entity));

    strcpy(Entity->CommandName, "help");

    Entity->ShortKey = 'h';

    Entity->CommandAction = PrintSEQHelp; 

    return Entity;
}



Firmware_Command *  SEQ_CommandsInit(){

    Firmware_Command * HeadOfCommands    = malloc(sizeof(HeadOfCommands));
    Firmware_Command * HelpCommand       = malloc(sizeof(HelpCommand));

    HelpCommand->Entity = SEQ_Help();

    HelpCommand->NextCommand = NULL;

    HeadOfCommands = HelpCommand;

    return HeadOfCommands;
}


void callcommand(Firmware_Command * ActiveCommands){
    ActiveCommands = malloc(sizeof * ActiveCommands);
    printf("inside callcommand \n");

    (ActiveCommands->Entity->CommandAction)();      

}


int ModulesInit() {

    int ParseRet;

    Firmware_Command * ActiveCommands = malloc(sizeof(ActiveCommands));

    ActiveCommands = SEQ_CommandsInit();
    callcommand(ActiveCommands);

    return 1;
} 



void main(void){
    int cmdInitRet;

    cmdInitRet = ModulesInit();
}
```

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: definitely I did

Comment: `CommandFrame * Entity = malloc(sizeof(Entity));` --> `CommandFrame * Entity = malloc(sizeof(*Entity));` and A lot of similar mistakes.

Comment: Plus: `ActiveCommands = malloc(sizeof * ActiveCommands);` assignment to local variable : result will not be seen by the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this several times in the code where you have a variable and you allocate memory for it, but then overwrite it with some other value. Or allocate over a previous value. Crucially though in the `callcommand` function you pass in a variable and then overwrite it's value with a new block of uninitialised memory and then try using it. You don't need to allocate memory - the passed in variable should be a valid pointer already.

```
void callcommand(Firmware_Command * ActiveCommands){
    // ActiveCommands = malloc(sizeof * ActiveCommands); Not needed at all
    printf("inside callcommand \n");

    (ActiveCommands->Entity->CommandAction)();      

}
```